# Nutrition: Yogurt vs Milk

Tags: milk, yogurt, ingredient-selection, nutrient-composition, dairy

I'm generally a fan of having quite a bit of whole milk/yogurt made with whole milk (no flavoured stuff, no extra sugar). I'm also quite finicky about calories. I have found that the low sugar content of yogurt vs. milk, and it's rather more savoury nature, mean I enjoy cooking and working with it much more. Is there any nutritional reason I can't just drop all milk consumption for yogurt? Do I lose anything other than the sugar (assuming equal calories consumed)?

EDIT: So to clarify what my question is:

What nutrients/chemicals are lost/changed in the process of converting milk to yogurt? As far as I can tell the most major one is the reduction in sugar per calorie which to me is a big bonus.

Comment: As a note, we do not address questions of "health" or general nutrition so if that's what you're looking for, you might want to look at the scope of the [health.se] instead. As far as I'm aware, they will address some questions on this topic but we do not have a nutrition site as of yet.

Comment: I edited out some of the more objectively off-topic aspects of your question. The question may still be closed by the community, but closing isn't a certainty. An argument can be made (and I would make that argument) that it is on-topic now. I like the question because it is scientifically interesting (I upvoted it after editing). Oh! and Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10753/homemade-yogurt-nutrition-info?rq=1

Comment: Hello Sean, and welcome to the site. You have probably noticed by now that we are quite strict in the type of questions we accept. Almost all of nutrition is off topic, but there is a small part which we do accept, and your question seems to fall under it - only it needs to be more more precisely defined. Your edit is already very good, but it needs a bit of final clarification. "What chemicals" makes the question unanswerable - there are hundreds of chemicals in both milk and yogurt, and probably not all of them are even identified. You probably mean "what chemicals which are relevant (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) to my diet" - but the big problem there is that there is no consensus in the world about a full list of such nutrients. For example, you seem to follow a diet in which the total amount of sugars is important - this is reasonably common, but not universal. And for most other stuff, there is even less of a consensus. So you would have to give us a list of the nutrients you find interesting, before we can tell you how they differ. We cannot do the work of deciding which nutrients *should* interest you, since this involves deciding which of thousands of nutritional theories is correct.